# not able to read a saved machine learning model in flask on a remote Ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, flask, scikit-learn

I have saved a Machine Learning model as 'finalized_model.sav' which I am using on a flask app. When I am running the below lines of code on my local desktop, it is running perfectly but running the same code on remote Ubuntu server is giving error:

```
@app.route('/studentData/', methods=['POST'])
def parsing_data():
    try:
        jsonData = request.get_json(force=True)
        data = json.loads(jsonData)  
        requiredData = data['statement']

        filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
        loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
        count_vect = pickle.load(open('count_vect', 'rb'))
        result = loaded_model.predict(count_vect.transform([requiredData]))
        out = {"studentId": str(result)}
        return json.dumps(out)
    except:
        return "invalid data"
```

I am wondering where could be the problem, seems like the problem is in loading the 'finalized_model.sav', although I have kept all my files in the same directory where my flask app(**init**.py) exists

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: there is no error message, I checked the log files. Commenting line loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb')) is making it run and uncommenting it, making it go to except: block

Comment: it has been resolved the scikit-learn was not installed on server and there was no error in log files with regard to that, also there was path error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a starter, change

```
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
```

to

```
filename = './finalized_model.sav'
```

If this still does not work, use the full path name

```
import os
filename = os.path.abspath(__file__) + os.sep + 'finalized_model.sav'
```